# How to open an object for viewing from the "datatable" table?

Tags: aura, lightning-datatable, custom-link

I am new to Salesforce. Now I am trying to solve this problem. I want to open it for viewing by clicking on the **name** of the **contact**. I did not find such an example in the documentation. Hope it is possible to implement it. Here's what I've managed to do so far: I made a data type like **link**, but I don't know how I can determine the path that I should follow in order to open the object for viewing by clicking on the link? For example, when I click on the **name** of the first **contact** on the screenshot, I follow this link `jack%20johns`.

[image]

How can I get into contacts, i.e. over here?

[image]

Here is the code for my init method:

```
init : function (component, event, helper) {
    component.set('v.columns', [
       { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'url', typeAttributes: {label: {fieldName: 'Name'}}, sortable: true  },
       { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email', type: 'email', sortable: true  },
       { label: 'Contact Level', fieldName: 'Contact_Level__c', sortable: true  },
    ]);
    helper.getDataFromDB(component, helper);
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to synthesize an attribute in your data with the record URL desired, and use that instead of `Name` as the `fieldName` for this column. Your `label` field remains `Name` to present that to the user.

I wrote a [post](https://www.ktema.org/2018/10/22/lightning-data-table-record-link/) about this long ago. Here's the summary:

When you load your data, you do something like this to add a URL field to each record:

```
records.forEach(function(item) {
    item['URL'] = '/lightning/r/Contact/' + item['Id'] + '/view';
}
```

and then you configure your columns to consume that data:

```
{
    label: 'Name', 
    fieldName: 'URL',
    type: 'url', 
    typeAttributes: { 
        label: {
            fieldName: 'Name'
        },
        target: '_self'
    },
    sortable: true 
}
```

Then you get the Name displayed, and a click takes you to the right page for the record.

You could also generate the URLs with the [Lightning navigation service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation) if you don't want the structure hard-coded in your component. That might add a bit of latency in the UI; it's worth checking.

Comment: Small world! I just posted an answer with a link to your article at the same time you did. @unique user, this should be the accepted answer rather than mine

Comment: Cool!!! You helped me a lot, this is a very useful knowledge. There is also a small clarification: now my sorting in the table is a little broken, because does it work by ID instead of Name? I understand correctly?

Comment: Yeeesss, I _think_ it's probably sorting by the field value rather than the label, so you may want to make this column non-sortable.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally used datatable, but from what I'm reading online, it seems that the fieldName specified in the top-level column object should be a field with the URL path in it, whereas typeAttributes.label.fieldName should be the name of a field containing the link's human-readable text.

In your code, the 'Name' field is being provided for both of these. To correct this, you'd need to replace the first fieldName with a field containing the URL. This could be a custom formula field, or (according to the following documentation) even a non-existent field that you "create" in JavaScript on the client side:

https://www.ktema.org/2018/10/22/lightning-data-table-record-link/